# How to replace an atypical pattern in a text file using sed

Tags: sed

I have an MRTG configuration file containing lines starting with the word "Target". Now in such lines there is a pattern starting with the character "#", and ending with character ":".

A sample line could look like these (note two types but start/end markers are still the same):

```
   Target[192.168.0.1_Gi1_1]: #Gi1/1:public@192.168.0.1:::::2

   Target[192.168.0.1_Gi1_31]: #Gi1/31:public@192.168.0.1:::::2
```

What I need is for sed to find these lines and replace the pattern `"#Gix/n:"` with 
`"ifInErrors#Gix/n&ifInErrors#Gix/n:"`, where x=`1-9`, n=`1-48`.

So the two sample lines shown above would be modified to these:

```
Target[192.168.0.1_Gi1_1]: ifInErrors#Gi1/1&ifInErrors#Gi1/1:public@192.168.0.1:::::2

Target[192.168.0.1_Gi1_31]: ifInErrors#Gi1/31&ifInErrors#Gi1/31:public@192.168.0.1:::::2
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a capturing group - you capture what you need in parentheses, and can reference it in the substitution. Like so:

```
 grep ^[[:space:]]*Target file | sed 's/\(#Gi[1-9]\/[1-9][0-9]*\):/ifInErrors\1\&ifInErrors\1:/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/Target/s/\(#Gi[0-9]*_[0-9]*:\)/ifInErrors\1\&ifInErrors\1/' input.txt
```

`sed '/Target/` is equivalent to `grep Target | sed`, except it involves one less process & one less pipe.

`s/` means 'substitution', the most common sed command; `s/foo/bar/` would replace instances of the string *foo* with *bar*, for example.

`/\(#Gi[0-9]*\/[0-9]*:\)` ... the brackets (which need to be escaped with a `\`) tell sed to mark everything between them as `\1` (or \2 for the second marked pattern, \3 for the third etc). `[0-9]*` means 'any number of numbers', and `\/` is an escaped `/` (it needs to be escaped because I'm using `/` as the separator for sed; if you use another separator, like `|`, then you wouldn't need to escape the /). So `#Gi[0-9]*\/[0-9]*:` is a pattern meaning 'start with #, followed by Gi, then any number of numbers, then /, then any number of numbers, ending with :'.

So `\1` matches whatever string is detected by the pattern `#Gi[0-9]*\/[0-9]*:` In the first string given in the question,

```
Target[192.168.0.1_Gi1_1]: #Gi1/1:public@192.168.0.1:::::2
##  The pattern #Gi[0-9]*\/[0-9]*: will match the substring
#Gi1/1:
```

...therefore `/ifInErrors\1\&ifInErrors\1/` tells sed 'replace `#Gi1/1:` with `ifInErrors#Gi1/1:&ifInErrors#Gi1/1:`'.

Some extra stuff: if you wanted to *just* print the lines that begin with 'Target', doing the sed substitution, you could use this line:

```
sed -n '/Target/s/\(#Gi[0-9]*\/[0-9]*:\)/ifInErrors\1\&ifInErrors\1/p'
```

`-n` tells sed 'don't print the output', and the `p` at the end tells it to print the lines sed is working on.

If you wanted to over-write your original file, you would use this:

```
sed -i '/Target/s/\(#Gi[0-9]*\/[0-9]*:\)/ifInErrors\1\&ifInErrors\1/'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?  This isn't really an answer without text explaining it.

Comment: @Seth Haha, fair enough, will edit in a explanation in a minute